# Add tag with custom class in WP TinyMCE

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

TinyMCE in WP has a great dropdown of format tags everyone uses, but is there a way to add a class to these tags? For example, there can be 2 `<p>` tags, one generating the basic `<p></p>` and another button (with a custom name) which generates `<p class="myclass"></p>`.

Comment: this is possible, but not out of the box (afaik). it can be easily done using an own plugin

Answer (score 3):

Definitely. Here's a tutorial if you want to do get dirty with the php: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/adding-custom-styles-in-wordpress-tinymce-editor/ the meat of which is in this filter:

```
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'tuts_mce_before_init' );
function tuts_mce_before_init( $settings ) {

    $style_formats = array(
        array(
            'title' => 'My Style',
            'selector' => 'p',
            'classes' => 'myclass',
        )
    );
    $settings['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats );
    return $settings;
}
```

and here's a plugin that'll do the work for you:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/